# available file handles is 0, how to increase

Tags: centos, files, ulimit, sysctl

Since some days, we're getting "Too Many Open Files" within an Java application while loading files. So i start searching on Google, and increased `fs.file-max` to `200000` in my `/etc/sysctl.conf`. After this, i run `sysctl -p`. But, this not helped. Because when i type `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`, it returns `2550    0       200000`. The first four digits vary, but the 0 is always 0, since i started looking..

What i'm doing wrong over here, or how can i fix this?

I'm running `CentOS release 5.9 (final)`, with one SSD, so i don't think that would be the problem. (Also, he is not fill, weak or anything and he run fine for months now.)

Another thing, but i'm not sure if it has anything with the issue; i'm able to create, destroy and edit files through SSH with nano/rm. And the Java application runs fine before this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: How *precisely* is your application being launched?

Comment: It's an Minecraft server (Java game). Launched with `/usr/bin/java -Xmx30720M -Xms30720M -jar (url) nogui`.

Comment: Okay, so you manually launched it from the command line? If so, from what shell? And did you issue a `ulimit -n` command first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the OS level `fs.file-max`, it's the maximum number of file handles your current user/group is allowed to have (per process) you want to edit. See `ulimit -n`.

You may adjust this limit as root by modifying `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Also make sure the limit is applied by adding `ulimit -SHn 8192` (or whatever limit you wish to have) to your `~/.bashrc`.